# Calling functions in array index

Tags: arrays, function, powershell

Short one this time. Why doesn't this work?

```
Function identity($x){$x}
@(1,2,3)[identity(1)]
```

(These do work)

```
identity(1)
@(1,2,3)[1]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make it execute `identity(1)` first by putting it parenthesis.

```
@(1,2,3)[(identity(1))]
```